# Не ставится laravel через composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer, php7, laravel5

Ос archlinux, все обновил, перезагрузил, php 7.2

Делаю

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

выдает мне

```
    Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v2.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v2.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Я понял, что он ругается на zip.so, но он включен, даже если сервер поднять написано что он подключился, даже просто почитав вывод "php -i", он тоже есть, версия 1.15.2 предпоследний, судя по pecl репозиторию. Причём, подняв homestead коробку и устанавливая в ней, всё окей, версия zip.so точно такая же, я не понимаю, в чем проблема.

Comment: Вам же в ошибке все написано. Установите `php7.2-dev` И по идее все работает.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов я же говорю у меня есть zip, он везде показывает что есть, именно при установке laravel он ругается, я не хочу переустанавливать php , а переустановить zip.so я пытаюсь, я спросил может я блин не знаю косяк какой то именно laravel или ещё что то, потому что другие пакеты ставяться

Comment: При установке `php7.2-dev` У вас просто установиться дополнитльные расширения к вашей `php7.2`. Это не переустановка и это действие не помешает.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов у меня на арче такого нет, даже в aur, я все таки поставил pecl и даже переустановил zip версия обновилась до 1.15.3 и всё равно тоже самое получаю